# Как в PostgreSQL исправить ошибку ограничения уникальности?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как исправить данную ошибку??

```
const CategoryTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    status BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);`

const ProductTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category VARCHAR(60) REFERENCES categories(name),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    photo TEXT,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    status TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Код ошибки:

> error cannot init DB: ОШИБКА: в целевой внешней таблице "categories"
> нет ограничения уникальности, соответствующего данным ключам (SQLSTATE
> 42830)

Comment: Что вы хотите получить? Понятно что нет уникальности в CategoryTable. Если оно уникально тогда добавьте уникальность. Если нет то будите ссылаться по другому

Comment: А где добавить ???     category VARCHAR(60) REFERENCES categories(name) UNIQUE, так что ли???

Comment: Может, всё-таки category VARCHAR(60) REFERENCES categories(id), а не categories(name)? Ключ есть у идентификатора, но не у колонки name.